# Similar sequences of coin flips

Tags: combinatorics

> An experiment consists of tossing a coin ten times and recording the results (heads or tails), for instance, HTHHTHTTTT could represent the result of an experiment. Two results are similar if they differ in no more than two place (or they are identical); thus, **H**THHTHT**T**TT is similar to **T**THHTHT**H**TT, but not to TTTHTHTHTT. Show that in a series of 100 experiments, there will be two with similar results.

I reasoned there are $2^{10}$ possibilities for the sequence of T's and H's. Each sequence will differ by one coin for 10 values. So total similar sequences is $2^{10}-10$. how to put this in terms of $n$ experiments is the tough part I'm running into.also number of ways to choose 1 so similar H or T out of 10 is trivially (10c1) adding that to (10c0) and (10c2) may also be part of the solution but where ? confusion in math is the worst kind

Comment: In which way does your reasoning has to do with the question?: "there will be **two** with similar results"

Comment: total number of possible coin flips minus number of ways with differing by one

Comment: so how is this one done? I reduced it to simpler case of 4 flips.  THHT,HHTT, ect would the same 2 in 100 cases be ' similar ' ?

Comment: calculus do u have a solution?

Answer (score 2):

For each result there are ten others that differ in one place.  Collect the $100$ sets of eleven, the original result and the ten differing in one place.  There are $1024$ possible results and there are $1100$ results among the sets, so there are two results in different sets that match.  The achieved results in those two sets are no more than two flips apart.

Added:  as an example, let us take series of five flips.  Say our first result is $TTTTT$.  We group every result within one flip of this, giving $\{TTTTT,HTTTT,THTTT,TTHTT,TTTHT,TTTTH\}$ for six of them.  There are $32$ possible results, so if we try six times we will have a match between two of the sets.  Maybe another result is $HTTTH$.  Its set will be $\{HTTTH,TTTTH,HHTTH,HTHTH,HTTHH,HTTTT\}$ and we note that $HTTTT$ and $TTTTH$ are common to these two sets.  Our two results differ in exactly two places, the first and last.

Comment: wow sounded super smart ross ,but i don't get it . do u know any links to similar problems? not that I doubt yours but looking to find some more easy to understand then come back to yours with hopefully an Aha experience

Comment: What is the largest possible cardinality of the set containing no similar results?

Comment: @user:  I don't know.  This shows that it is at most $\lfloor \frac {1024}{11}\rfloor$ but I suspect it is rather smaller.

Comment: Ross how did u get that ? do u mean 1024c11?

Comment: @RandinMichaelDivelbiss:   No, I meant division rounding down.  Those are floor brackets.  My argument works whenever you can guarantee the same number is in two different groups of $11$.  There can be at most that many disjoint groups of $11$.  I have ignored the fact that the numbers in a group share a structure, which may mean you can't find that many disjoint groups, but I don't know how to prove it.  This shows that you can't have more than $93$ flips without having two that are similar.

Comment: ah ok I just didn't see why the floor function would be used on this problem . I did think it was at first but now u have explained why , thank u

Comment: i think you nailed this one Ross, can u tell me where else this problem is to be found online ? and may I ask if u teach any classes in probability,  number theory,  combinatorics,  or statistics?

Comment: the kicker was seeing for 5 flips there are six including the first flip that are disimilar by 1 . so you are saying this is like pigeonhole principle ?

Comment: @RandinMichaelDivelbiss:  it is exactly the pigeonhole principle.  You have $1100$ pigeons, the flips and the strings one space away, and $1024$ holes, the different $10$ flip sequences.

Comment: when u say " one space away" u mean one flip different ? as In your example with 5 ? that their are six sequences generated for the 5 flips ?

Comment: @RandinMichaelDivelbiss:  that is correct.  There is the original sequence plus one with each flip changed.

Comment: your the man ( again ) Ross! ( that's why I am wondering where u teach so I can enroll :)) i was intuitively on the right track so I must give myself credit . instead of 2^1o-10 it was actually adding sequences not subtracting though . and the 10 didn't include the first sequence,  nor did I account for a multiple of this into 1024 total sequences